# Cómo Integrar un Mini calendario en un calendario general con Fullcalender

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, fullcalendar

estoy usando el plugin Fullcalendar para crear un calendario de eventos en mi proyecto. El registro y modificación de los eventos ya lo tengo hecho, al igual que el calendario general, sin embargo me gustaria agregar en la parte izquierda un mini calendario (al estilo datepicker) el cual sea un complemento extra que permita por ejemplo cambiar el año, el mes o mostrar el dia del calendario grande (calendaro general) directamente desde el minicalendario, algo parecido a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este plugin hace algo más o menos asi (no es gratuito):
https://www.web2cal.com/index.php/ajax-events-calendar/demo/46-mail-calendar pero me gustaria lograrlo con Fullcalendar, intente agregando un datepicker pero a partir de ahí me he trabado y no se muy bien como lograr concretar la idea...

Hasta el momento tengo el siguiente código:

Archivo Calendario.html:

```
           <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
           <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-calendar" id="icono"></i> + Nuevo Evento</button><br>
            <div id="calendarioPeque"></div>
          </div>
           <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
             <div id="Calendario"></div>
           </div>
```

Calendario.js:

```
      $(document).ready(function() { 

fecha = "";
$("#calendarioPeque").datepicker({ 
    onSelect: function(date1) {
    fecha = date1; 
    hora = "06:00:00";
    dateTime = fecha + " " + hora;

      //$("#inicioAdd").val(dateTime);
      //$("#eventoAgregar").modal('show');
    } 

                });
         });


        $("#Calendario").fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    header: {
        left: 'today,prev,next,month,agendaWeek',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'MiBoton,MiBoton2' 
    }, 
    customButtons: {
      MiBoton: {
        text: 'Tipo Eventos',
        click: function() {


        }
      }, 

        MiBoton2: {
        text: 'Estado Eventos',
        click: function() {

          //$("#calendarioPeque").focus();

        }
      }

    }, 

    dayClick:function(date,jsEvent,view) {

        $("#inicioAdd").val(date.format());
        $("#eventoAgregar").modal();

      }, 

    events: 'http://www.miagenda.com/ajax/EventosAjax.php?op=Mostrar', 

      eventClick:function(calEvent,jsEvent,view) {
        $("#idEvento").val(calEvent.id);
        $("#titulo").val(calEvent.title);
        $("#tipo").val(calEvent.tipo);
        $("#descripcion").val(calEvent.descripcion);
        $("#inicio").val(calEvent.start);
        $("#fin").val(calEvent.end);
        $("#color").val(calEvent.color);
        $("#colorTexto").val(calEvent.textColor);
        $("#estadoEvento").val(calEvent.estado);
        $("#eventoModificar").modal('show');
      }


  });
```

Vista: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]:
Cualquier idea o codigo que tengan y puedan darme se los agradeceria... si conocen otro plugin gratuito que me sirva para hacer esto, también es bienvenido.

Comment: Podrias usar [jqwidgets](https://www.jqwidgets.com/), uno de sus widgets tiene el nombre de [jqxScheduler](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxscheduler/index.htm), para mi es mejor que el FullCalendar, y no solo tiene para calendarios sino una galería de otros controles. Te adjuntos algunos ejemplos. [defaultfunctionality](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxscheduler/defaultfunctionality.htm?fresh) [scheduler-timeline-views](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxscheduler/scheduler-timeline-views.htm?fresh) [scheduler-agenda-view](https: